# How to convert string count into number?

Tags: views

How to convert string count into number? I have string count column in views i.e. by using the view aggregating I am counting the nodes of content, along with this I have **field_number** column i.e. from content type.

Now I want to subtracts these two column, while using math-expression its taking the string count column as string its not considering the count number.

Is there any solution to subtract these two fields?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php

Comment: @BipinK: where can i implement it please can u explain me with more clarity....if u dont mind

Answer (score 1):

Drupal doesn't provide any conversion of value in "Math Expression" field. So we need to fix it in another way, for example following these steps:

- Add two new columns "string count" and  "field_number" same as previously added, excluding

  - When add fields tick "Exclude from display" checkbox
  - Select "Plain Text" to "Formatter" dropdown
- After it, edit "Math-Expression" field, in "Expression" textarea write your mathematical expression with that newly added fields, e.g. `[string_count_1] - [field_number_1]`

Comment: do we need to add one more time both the column in view?

Comment: If you want display only plain text of that two columns, without any formating/HTML tags(i.e. <p>), then you can directly edit both columns and  Select "Plain Text" to "Formatter" dropdown of both columns.
Else we need to add one more time both the column in view

Comment: please check the scrren shot there is no formatter dropdown for tittle count column

Comment: Is there link on "Title" field required? If not then remove check on "Link this field to the original piece of content" check-box.
Else you must add new same column and make it "Exclude from display".

Comment: let me check so over all u mean to say for 1]field_max_room_capacity need to choose text from formator drop down 2] and for title need to uncheck link this field to the original piece of content then need                                                                                                  3] need to add math expression following to field token right?

Comment: Yes, exactly you are on the right track :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31745/discussion-between-neethu-and-php-weblineindia).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)

> This module allows the admin account (user 1) to add fields, filters
>   and sorts to views which use PHP code. It also supports additional
>   accounts when the core PHP Filter module is enabled

Then add PHP field in `Global category` and do that with php

in `OUTPUT` of field write something like(it is example and you should write it according your field)

```
//first dpm($data) and dpm($row) to see what data exists there then 
echo intval($data->field_a['raw'][0]['value']) + $data->field_b['raw'][0]['value'];
```

Comment: I added something like this   <?php
echo intval($data->title_1['raw'][0]['value']) + $data->field_max_room_capacity['raw'][0]['value'];
?>                                                                                                                             but its retaining zero value in column

Comment: @neethu did you try dpm($data) before it to see what you have? and also please provide `dpm($data->title_1['raw'][0]['value']);` result for me.tnx

Comment: thanks, well is it something over all                       <?php      dpm($data->title_1['raw'][0]['value']);                                                          echo intval($data->title_1['raw'][0]['value']) +                                   $data->field_max_room_capacity['raw'][0]['value'];                                                        ?>                                                                                                                       Sorry if i am wrong

Comment: @neethu I want see the exist data to help you more, final solution is something like `<?php  echo intval($data->title_1['raw'][0]['value']) + $data->field_max_room_capacity['raw'][0]['value']; ?>`

Comment: please find the screen shot u may find what mistake i am doing

Comment: i used the above code but its retaining zero value again ...not calculating:(

Comment: **why you check "Link this field to main content"?(uncheck it)**when you try dpm, it should have some output, where is them?
please dpm($row) and dpm($data) and take screenshot of dpm result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31740/discussion-between-neethu-and-zhilevan).

Comment: After discussion I find out he want subtract count title .and I advise him change the question.